# Greedy algorithm exercise not working properly

Tags: c++, greedy

I'm in high school and having a test soon, one of the topics being the Greedy algorithm. I'm having an unknown issue with this exercise: "It is given an array of N integers. Using the Greedy algorithm, determine the largest number that can be written as a multiplication of two of the array elements" (Sorry if it's a bit unclear, I'm not a native English speaker).

Now, what I had in mind to solve this exercise is this: Find the largest two numbers and the lowest two numbers (in case they are both negative) and display either the multiplication of the two largest or of the two lowest, depending on which number is larger.

This is what I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a[100001],n;

int main()
{

int max1=-1000001,max2=-1000001,min1=1000001,min2=1000001,x;
cin>>n;

for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    cin>>a[i];

    if (a[i]>=max2)
    {
        if (a[i]>=max1)
        {
            x=max1;
            max1=a[i];
            max2=x;
        }
        else max2=a[i];
    }

    if (a[i]<=min2)
    {
        if (a[i]<=min1)
        {
            x=min1;
            min1=a[i];
            min2=x;
        }
        else min2=a[i];
    }
}

if (n==1)
    cout<<n;
else if (max1*max2>=min1*min2)
    cout<<max1*max2;
else cout<<min1*min2;

return 0;
}
```

Yes, I know the way I wrote it is untidy/ugly. The code, however, should function properly and I tested it with both the example provided by the exercise and lots of different situations. They all gave the right result. The problem is that the programming exercises website gives my code a 80/100 score, not because of the time but because of the wrong answers.

I've already spent more than 2 hours looking at this code and I just can't figure out what's wrong with it. Can anyone point out the flaw? Thanks <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most likely comes from the fact that multiplying 2 int's will give you an int. An int usually has a range of `-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`.

If you then multiply `2,147,483,647 * 2` for example you get `-2`. Similarly taking `2,147,483,647 + 1` will give you `-2147483648`. When the value reaches it's max it deals with that by going to the lowest possible value.

To partially solve the problem you just need to cast 1 of the variables you multiply to a 64-bit integer. For modern C++ that would be `int64_t`.

```
if (n==1)
    cout<<n;
else if (static_cast<int64_t>(max1)*max2>=static_cast<int64_t>(min1)*min2)
    cout<<static_cast<int64_t>(max1)*max2;
else cout<<static_cast<int64_t>(min1)*min2;
```

But you will still be able to get too big number if both the values are big enough. So you need the full range of a `uint64_t`, the unsigned version.

So we need to cast to a `uint64_t` instead, but then you run into another issue with the numbers below 0. So first you should convert you min1 and min2 to the equivalent positive numbers, then cast to `uint64_t`.

```
uint64_t positive_min1, positive_min2;
if (min1 < 0 && min2 < 0) {
    positive_min1 = min1*-1;
    positive_min2 = min2*-1;
}
else {
    positive_min1 = 0;
    positive_min2 = 0;
}
```

Now you can go ahead and do

```
if (n==1)
    cout<<n;
else if (static_cast<uint64_t>(max1)*max2>=positive_min1*positive_min2)
    cout<<static_cast<int64_t>(max1)*max2;
else cout<<positive_min1*positive_min2;
```

No need to cast positive_min1 & 2 since it was already converted to `uint64_t`.

Since you are casting `max1` to unsigned, you should probably check that it's not below 0 first.

If signed and unsigned is not familiar concepts you can read about that and the different data types [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).